# Writing a kafka topic when consumer is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-producer-api

I was trying to integrate kafka-storm. I have just started with few examples.

I was able to run examples from GitHub. Next I am trying to write a Producer class in eclipse to publish messages to kafka topic using KAFKA PRODUCER API.

**Scenario1:**

When my consumer-shell is running using say topic test, and test i run my producer class. I am able to see my consumer-shell with all published messages.

**Scenario2**

I have not started my consumer-shell( say consumer is down). And I run my producer class. The messages is getting published to the kafka.

Now if the messages are published, and now after downtime if I start my consumer shell, Its not reading the messages already published topic.

Why? I suppose it maintains log for topic consumption. Shouldn't it be reading the messages?

Is there any config parameter which i need to mention?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
props.put("zk.connect", "localhost:2181");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

        for ( int nEvents=0; nEvents<events;nEvents++)
        {
          String ip="192.168.2."+rnd.nextInt(255);
          String msg=getNextTradeData(); // Class to generate data
          KeyedMessage<String,String> data=new KeyedMessage<String, String>("TradeFrequency",ip,msg);
          Thread.sleep(100);
          System.out.println(msg);
          producer.send(data);  

        }
producer.close();

}
```

Or is there anything I need to do to change the consumer. I am using the consumer-shell provided in the package, and starting it using

```
  bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic first-topic
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the `kafka-console-consume` it will read from the current offset. This is, the offset `NOW()` and not from the past.

To see if the messages were published you have two options:

1. Use the `--from-beginning` option, to read from the beginning of the topic

   bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic first-topic --from-beginning
2. Persist the state of the console-consumer in the zookeeper/kafka using the `--consumer.config` option

   bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic first-topic  --consumer.config /home/sql-injection/consumer-config.txt

according to this [nice page](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs) the parameters you need on the consumer config are: `consumer.id`, `client.id`.

Comment: Thanks, its works for me in this scenario. Now in this case everytime it will start from the bignning of the log i suppose( although I need to check still). But if I wish to read from wherever it left or may be say the (last offset read+1). What would be my approach?

Comment: @NishantM use the consumer config option, that should allow you to resume from the last offset